# How do I actually put data inside the page cache?

Tags: neo4j

Quoting the documentation, **each file in the Neo4j store is accessed through the Neo4j page cache**. So I take that every time a query happens the page cache will be accessed, right? I've tried adding an example graph (like The Movie Graph), then executing example queries through the web interface like

```
MATCH (bacon:Person {name:"Kevin Bacon"})-[*1..4]-(hollywood)
RETURN DISTINCT hollywood
```

So why is that that when I check **:play sysinfo** it still says **No statistics available.** under Page Cache?

By the way, I also went to **conf/neo4j.properties** and set **dbms.pagecache.memory=2g** (also removing the # comment mark), because I assumed it is required that I define a value for the page cache memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data is always accessed through the page cache, even if you haven't explicitly configured a size for it. The page cache statistics in `:sysinfo` are just not available in the Community Edition of Neo4j.